# How to click on a button inside a side bar label with Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I´m trying to click a button inside a side bar label:

```
<span class="sidebar-label">
    Exportar Listagem
</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
driver.get("https://ispot2.faturaiqos.pt")
html = driver.page_source
exp = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Exportar Listagem")
exp.click()
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Python Testes/Ispot JP.py", line 25, in <module>
exp = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Exportar Listagem")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 317, in find_element_by_link_text
return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 745, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Exportar Listagem"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.141)
(Driver info: chromedriver=84.0.4147.141 (80c974bf7990b9735a8e885046fc5c9b1da4796c-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#1132}),platform=Linux 5.4.79-v7+ armv7l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as ***Exportar Listagem*** you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='sidebar-label' and contains(., 'Exportar Listagem')]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='sidebar-label' and normalize-space()='Exportar Listagem']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sidebar-label' and contains(., 'Exportar Listagem')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sidebar-label' and normalize-space()='Exportar Listagem']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Perfect :), my next question is: i got to this "Exportar Listagem" page and now i need to fill 2 date forms before clicking the button "Exportar"
Date From
<input data-v-412102b4="" type="text" placeholder="2020-11-12" class="w-full form-control form-input form-input-bordered flatpickr-input active" name="From">
Date To
<input data-v-412102b4="" type="text" placeholder="2020-12-12" class="w-full form-control form-input form-input-bordered flatpickr-input" name="To">
Click Button:
<span class="">Exportar</span>

Comment: @PeterPan Sounds to be a different question all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.